# R - dplyr mutate using lookup tables

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hi I have a data table (with names and values), a reference table and a limit table, and I'd like to create a new column in the data table, where the value of the actual row is compared to the reference value of the matching name and to the limit for the respective column. Here are some sample data to make it clearer:

**reference table**

```
> refTable
  name value1 value2
1   aa    1.2    0.4
2   bb    3.4    2.3
3   cc    2.1    1.1
```

**limit table**

```
> limits
  value1 value2
1    2.1    1.8
```

**data table**

```
> dataTable
  name value1 value2
1   aa    1.0    1.4
2   aa    2.4    2.1
3   cc    2.6    1.8
4   bb    2.2    2.4
5   aa    3.4    3.0
6   cc    2.9    0.8
```

And in the end I'd like to have new columns in the data table (like `value1_pass` and `value2_pass`) that are calculated like:
`value1_pass = ((matching name's value1 in reference table) - (value1 of data table)) < (limit of value1)`

I'm using dplyr and data.frames, and I was trying to use mutate for this, but I can't figure out how to use the reference values and the limit values inside the mutate equation. What is the proper way of doing this? (Ideally I'd like to have/create only the result columns, but I don't really mind copying new columns to the data table with the matching reference values if that makes it easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
dataTable %>%
    left_join(refTable, by = "name", suffix = c("",".ref")) %>%
    mutate(value1_pass = ((value1.ref - value1) < limits$value1),
           value2_pass = ((value2.ref - value2) < limits$value2),
           value1.ref = NULL, value2.ref = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work, using dplyr:

```
> dt %>% mutate(value1_limit = limitt$value1, value2_limit = limitt$value2) %>% 
+   inner_join(reft, by = 'name') %>% 
+         mutate(value1_pass = value1.y - value1.x < value1_limit, value2_pass = value2.y - value2.x < value2_limit) %>% 
+                 select(1,2,3,8,9) %>% rename(value1 = value1.x, value2= value2.x)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  name  value1 value2 value1_pass value2_pass
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>       <lgl>      
1 aa       1      1.4 TRUE        TRUE       
2 aa       2.4    2.1 TRUE        TRUE       
3 cc       2.6    1.8 TRUE        TRUE       
4 bb       2.2    2.4 TRUE        TRUE       
5 aa       3.4    3   TRUE        TRUE       
6 cc       2.9    0.8 TRUE        TRUE       
>
```